# android home application not starting after reboot why?

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

i have an android tv application and need to make it launcher application and home application
i added the below code in manifest

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.LandingActivity"

        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also in **Settings -> Default -> Home App -> i select my own application**
So when i click home button in device it navigate to the launcher activity of my application, but when i restart the device , the application set as default doesn't run by default and immediately

i checked the settings and make sure that is selected by default.

So why the app is not opened by default after reboot?

Comment: why did u used android.intent.category.LAUNCHER while u using android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER?

Comment: i am trying to remove the android.intent.category.LAUNCHER

Comment: But also not working i am confused !

Comment: @r4jiv007 yes i found a solution to uninstall the main home page of the application because in my case i don't need it, i need to start directly my own app when the box started.

Comment: So what i did is to run .adb from terminal in android studio and run the command that show me all the system packages in the box, then i searched for the package name of the initial home page of the device, and i run the command that uninstall this application (which is home page)

Comment: After that i restart the box and my app run automatically

Comment: @Malo I did the same but somehow i feel the system has another service which tries to restore the previous app. I was able to launch my app when home button is pressed after I uninstalled the default app, I hope i'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

try

```xml
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: Also not working, i am using amlogic android box for TV, i unplug the charger and restart it to try if the app will launch by default but no result !!

Comment: the box have android 11.1